# Equivalent of C# HttpRequest in PHP

Tags: c#, php, httprequest

I'm trying to find the equivalent of System.Web.HttpRequest in PHP for the current page, as I would like to access the current variables. Most, I realise, you can get from $_SERVER, but there seems to be some missing from there (e.g. Referer and cookie).

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referer is found in the `$_SERVER` as the key `HTTP_REFERER`.

Cookies can be accessed through `$_COOKIE` and `set_cookie()`.

Comment: Thank you! I just couldn't see referer, but then realised that doesn't exist in the current context!

Comment: yep, you've got to make your browser refer or fake a referer request.